# Compare a Context inside Adapter with an Activity's context

Tags: android-adapter

I'm tring to evaluate if the Context inside the WordAdapter at a given time is the same as the Context of a given activity.

For me, the expression inside the 'If' should evaluate to 'TRUE', but it is not. How should I do this?

[image: PNG from the Debugger]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I got a way to do what i need:
[image]